# Replace a string to unicode characters

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a string like `blah blah ::e||1f1e6-1f1ea:: blah blah` and I want to convert it to `blah blah  blah blah`.

can be written as `\u{1f1e6}\u{1f1ea}`.

I used the code below but it converts to `\u{1f1e6}\u{1f1ea}` this string, not the symbol.

```
str.replace(/\:\:e\|\|(.*?)\:\:/g, function(x) { return x.replace(/-/g, '\}\\u\{'); }).replace(/\:\:e\|\|(.*?)\:\:/g, "\\u\{$1\}" );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1f1e6` and `1f1ea` are the hexadecimal Unicode code points for that character. You can use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint), but you'll need to use a PolyFill for IE:

```
text.replace(/::e\|\|([a-f0-9\-]+)::/g, function(match, text) {
    var code_points = text.split('-').map(function(n) {
        return parseInt(n, 16);
    });

    return String.fromCodePoint.apply(undefined, code_points);
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is working but number of `-` is varying. It is between 0 and 7. I can check the number of `-` and then write this code using `function(match, a, b, c...)` but I wonder is there a better way to do this.

Comment: @NaimBerkTumer: You could just treat them as a big group and split them with `.split('-')`. See my edit.